# Mass-Listing Twitter Users

Tags: twitter

I am looking for a method to mass-list all [Twitter Employees](http://twitter.com/about/employees) to a public list of my own.
It sounds like it should be within their [TOS](http://twitter.com/tos) here is what I got from their [Policies](http://twitter.zendesk.com/forums/26257/entries/18311):

> **Spam**: You may not use the Twitter service for the purpose of spamming
>   anyone. What constitutes “spamming”
>   will evolve as we respond to new
>   tricks and tactics by spammers. Some
>   of the factors that we take into
>   account when determining what conduct
>   is considered to be spamming are:
>
> - If you have followed a large amount of users in a short amount of time;
> - If you have followed and unfollowed people in a short time period,
>     particularly by automated means
>     (aggressive follower churn);
> - If you repeatedly follow and unfollow people, whether to build
>     followers or to garner more attention
>     for your profile;
> - If you have a small number of followers compared to the amount of
>     people you are following;
> - If you add a large number of unrelated users to lists in an attempt
>     to spam a service or link;
> - If you have attempted to "sell" followers, particularly through
>     tactics considered aggressive
>     following or follower churn;
> - Using or promoting third-party sites that claim to get you more followers
>     (such as follower trains, sites
>     promising "more followers fast," or
>     any other site that offers to
>     automatically add followers to your
>     account);

This point

> If you add a large number of unrelated users to lists in an attempt
>   to spam a service or link;

does not seem to include Twitter employees. If someone knows otherwise let me know.

The method should have all/most of the following requirements.

- Services that follow Twitter's TOS
- (Page scraping - I am not so sure about)
- Quick and simple (I could do it in 15-30 mins but thats just wasting time and getting distracted everytime I open a user's profile)
- Ability to append to existing list (I started without the employee page from @ev replies to other users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up using these lists by Twitter:

- [Developers](https://twitter.com/twitter/lists/developers)
- [Engineering](https://twitter.com/twitter/lists/engineering)

Comment: Your link is down, Twitter doesn't have that list anymore. Here are the current lists they have that are relevant to what you're looking for: [Developers](https://twitter.com/twitter/lists/developers), [Engineering](https://twitter.com/twitter/lists/engineering). See the rest of Twitter's lists [here](https://twitter.com/twitter/lists).

Comment: @ellekaie just suggest an edit/edit the answer

Comment: Done, thank you for suggesting.